# How to left join column in other way

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to map right column to left but i am getting error at select statement as Incorrect syntax near 'select'.Expecting ID

```
create table [AdventureWorks2014].[abc] as
select a.*,
        b.*
from [Production].[Product] a
left join(
select distinct ProductID,Shelf
from [Production].[ProductInventory]
)b
on a.ProductID = b. ProductID;
```

Comment: are you trying to create a table as well?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `SELECT INTO`:

```
select p.*, pi.shelf
into [AdventureWorks2014].[abc]
from [Production].[Product] p left join
     (select distinct ProductID, Shelf
      from [Production].[ProductInventory] pi
     ) pi
     on p.ProductID = pi.ProductID;
```

Notes:

- I am not aware that SQL Server supports `CREATE TABLE AS`.
- The columns in a table need to have unique names.  If you use `*`, you will get `ProductId` twice.
- Abbreviations of the table names is the best naming conventions; meaningless letters such as `a` and `b` should be avoided.